# Emailer font color and size issue

Tags: html, css

I have created a html markup for weekly digest which forwarded to the subscribed user.
My problem is i put a link in side the template and it is working fine for gmail and hotmail but when i check in yahoo the link color and font size is not proper 
Here is my html markup

```
<a style="font-size:11px;list-style-type: none;margin-left: 0;color:#4A9BA2;text-decoration: none" href="#">Text</a>
```

I tried this also but its also not working in yahoo.

```
.yshortcuts {
      border-bottom: none !important;
      color:#4A9BA2 !important;
      font-size: 11px !important;
      text-decoration: none !important;
      }

      .yshortcuts a span {  border-bottom: none !important;
      color:#4A9BA2 !important;
      font-size: 11px !important;
      text-decoration: none !important; }
```

This is happing because after a yahoo adds a span tag in side a applying its own css.Like this way.

```
<a style="font-size:11px;list-style-type: none;margin-left: 0;color:#4A9BA2;text-decoration: none" href="#"><span id="lw_1294820231_7" class="yshortcuts">Text</span></a>
```

Some one please help me i am stacking with this problem.

Comment: Just to understand, this markup is going in HTML emails?  If so, you're really pushing the boundaries of what's possible with email browsers....What does it look like in Outlook '07 or '10?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to take advantage of the precedence rules of CSS. The CSS selector that should take precedence is `a span.yshortcuts`. With this selector you should be able to override the color defined in the Yahoo CSS.

```
a span.yshortcuts {
    color:#4A9BA2 !important;
    font-size:11px !important;
}
```

This has higher precedence and should be used by the css interpreter.

Comment: that won't work because Yahoo is using `!important`. If you do the above but also use `!important` then you'll take precedence.

Comment: Oh I missed the use of `!important` – fixed the answer according to Spudleys hint. @saorabh: Please try it again.